# Ensure that a backup is fully functional

Tags: sql-server, database

This is how I am planning to backup my database. How can I check whether the backup created is fully functional?

```
BACKUP DATABASE mytest TO DISK = 'C:\mytest.BAK'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check about `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` -

```
BACKUP DATABASE [db] TO DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\db.bak'
GO
DECLARE @backupSetId AS INT
SELECT @backupSetId = position
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
WHERE database_name = N'db'
    AND backup_set_id = (
        SELECT MAX(backup_set_id)
        FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
        WHERE database_name = N'db'
    )
IF @backupSetId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'D:\BACKUP\db.bak' WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You restore it to your backup server. Old rule: Backups do not exist unless they have been restored for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you restore your database backup to a fresh installation. In other words, you do exactly what you would have to do if you were recovering from a disaster.

There are methods to check the integrity of backups, but the best is to do a mock disaster recovery at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this,

When you are taking backup using SSMS wizard, enable the option

Verify backup when finished.

Explanation:

Verify backup integrity check box

```
Verify that the backup set is complete and that all volumes are readable.
```

[image]